# ViewPager setOffScreenPageLimit > 2 doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` in which the first Fragment has a children fragments that is shown depending on certain conditions. whenever i set `setOffscreenPageLimit()` on the `ViewPager > 2`, Children `fragments` won't show up, else every thing works fine.

Any Solutions??

Comment: What is the mumber of fragments that your viewpager has.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira 6 fragments

Comment: @AkhileshPatil Sorry if u didn't get what i was asking for, one of the 'ViewPager' fragment got other children fragments, If i set pageLimit on the viewPager (children fragment) of the (first viewpager fragment) won't show up

Answer (score 0):

I was using `getFragmentManager()` inside the parent `Fragment` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` while adding the child fragment which caused this strange behavior.